# Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise user table with carrier wave and an avatar column in my data base. When running the website it says 'undefined method `avatar'

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 item" >
        <div class="timeline-block">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <a href="">
                    <%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url, class: 'media-object' %>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="media-object">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <a href="#" class="pull-right text-muted"><i class="icon-reply-all-fill fa fa-2x "></i></a>
                  <a href=""><%= name post %></a>
                  <span><%= (post.created_at).to_formatted_s(:short) %></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
              <p><%= post.user_post %></p>
            </div>

            <div class="view-all-comments">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> View all
              </a>
              <span>10 comments</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  #attr_accessor :email, :password, :remember_me, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Have no idea what is going on. On other applications I made the associations worked.

Comment: Can you show us the code from the `User` model?

Comment: yes I have put the user model up on the question

Comment: Have you restarted your application server?

Comment: Your question has insufficient info to get the problem resolved. Please provide related info, e.g. `User` model's code.

Comment: Yes I did and it still gives me the same error both before and after

Comment: please post the exact error message..... may be post.user returning nil and you are trying to call avatar on nil .

Answer (score 0):

You have `mount_uploader` in your `User` model twice.

Also, did you run the following code?

```
rails g migration add_avatar_to_users avatar:string
rake db:migrate
```

The normal reason for getting an 'undefined method' error on an active record model is that the DB columns are not there, so I suspect that is the problem.

If not, please post the exact error message and stack trace as you see it on the screen, along with the contents of your migration file and the `AvatarUploader`.

*Edit:*

You are missing the active record associations in your models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: The column is there

Comment: OK. What's in the `AvatarUploader`?

Comment: AvatarUploader is a generated class from carrier wave

Comment: It is a problem with post.user I think. I can access the post.user_id variable, but not anything post.user.

Comment: See updated answer: You are missing your active record associations